# exoplayer- automatic change of quality is not working (hls)

Tags: android, video, http-live-streaming, exoplayer

i have little problem with exoplayer. almost everything works fine when i try to play video from hls stream. hls stream contains 3 different sets of chunklists each for different bandwidth.

but hls adaptive streaming is not working and player works only with one chunklist and with slow internet connection is this solution unusable.

source code:

```
 BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
 TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
 TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);
 this.simpleExoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(getActivity(), trackSelector);
 this.videoPlayer.setPlayer(this.simpleExoPlayer);

 DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this.getActivity(), Util.getUserAgent(this.getActivity(), "appName"));
 MediaSource mediaSource = new HlsMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(Uri.parse(hlsUrl));
 this.simpleExoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
 this.simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

i tried to implement MediaSourceEventListener too and onDownstreamFormatChanged is called only once in the moment of player initialization.

thanks for any advices

Comment: Your initialization looks correct, could you post the HLS file you're trying to play? Are you sure there are no issues with the HLS file? You might also want to step through the `TrackSelection` and put a break point where it iterates through the `Formats` to see if they're properly being parsed.

Comment: @jakub can you please tell me how you do that like change quality of video depend on internet speed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key here is you need to pass the same "bandwidthMeter" you passed in to AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory to the dataSourceFactory too.
Only after these changes the Exoplayer does adaptive streaming as expected.

```
String userAgent = "XYZPLAYER";
DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory httpDataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(userAgent, bandwidthMeter, DefaultHttpDataSource.DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, DefaultHttpDataSource.DEFAULT_READ_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, true);
DefaultDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, bandwidthMeter, httpDataSourceFactory);
```